# unexpected type 'QVariant'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qgis

I'm updated a 2.14 GQIS plugin code to 3.X with a UI.
I want to add the attribute of a layer in a QTextEdit

When i run my code i got this message:

```
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVariant'
```

I already search and find some fix to this error but none of them can solve it;

I try with

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant',2)
```

But didn't work either.

Here is a example of the code

```
def MAJ_AFFICHAGE_FENETRE(self):
    layer = self.COUCHE_DEPARTEMENT_SELECTIONNEE()
    i = self.INDICE_TABLE_ATTRIBUTAIRE()
    
    if i != -1:
        iterator = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(i+1))
        feature = next(iterator)
        self.ZOOM()
        if type(feature["InfoMairie"]) != None:
            self.InfoMairie.setText(feature["InfoMairie"])
        else:
            self.InfoMairie.setText("")
```

For more information:

```
dir(feature["InfoMairie"])
```

['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getnewargs**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**mod**', '**mul**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**rmod**', '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']

```
print (feature["InfoMairie"])
```

03 23 39 68 32
mairiestaubin02@sfr.fr

If some one know how to fix this

Comment: what are the outputs of `print(feature["InfoMairie"])` and `dir(feature["InfoMairie"])`?

Comment: print (feature["InfoMairie"]) outputs : 
03 23 39 68 32
 mairiestaubin02@sfr.fr